# How to make immutable variable pointing mutable data in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm having trouble understand how to achieve following:
I would like a reference to vector that i cannot change, containing data that i can change(c++ T* const  equivalent)
Is that achievable in rust syntax?

```
let mut a = Vec::new()
a.push(1) // should be allowed
a = Vec::new() // should be disallowed.
```

mut seems to be allowing mutability on both levels

Comment: You might be looking for [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html)

Comment: It still possible to change inner value: `fn f(x: &RefCell<Vec<u8>>) { *x.borrow_mut() = Vec::new(); }`

Comment: This is not possible in Rust. Any method that borrows a value mutably can reassign it. Even `Vec::push` can copy the content of the `Vec` to a new location and replace the old `Vec` with the new one. This happens when there is not enough remaining capacity.

Comment: This sounds like a [X/Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Maybe we can help you better if you tell us what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @aloso Im not trying to achieve anything just discussing language semantics. I'm just exploring language.

Comment: @Daber `Vec` is not a bare pointer, it's a structure, like an std::vector. The Rust version of bare pointers would be references. A `T* const` is an immutable binding to a mutable reference, a `const T*` is a mutable binding to an immutable reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```rust
let mut a = Vec::new()
```

does not create a reference to a vector; rather it creates a variable bound to the vector itself. It is the equivalent to this in C++:

```cpp
std::vector<int> a;
```

If you want an immutable reference to a mutable vector, you would have something like this:

```rust
let mut a = vec![1,2,3];

let r = &mut a;
r.push(4);
```

In the above snippet, `r` is an immutable variable bound to a reference to the mutable vector `a`. If you try to re-assign `r` to be a reference to another vector:

```rust
let mut b = vec![4,5,6];

r=&mut b;
r.push(7);
```

you will get this error:

```
9 |     r=&mut b;
  |     ^^^^^^^^ cannot assign twice to immutable variable
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=35ef336620533a1534856014edd4428b)

Note however that due to the fact that Rust allows shadowing, you can use 'let' to create a new binding that shadows the old one in the same scope, so you could do this:

```rust
let mut a = vec![1, 2, 3];

let r = &mut a;
r.push(4);

let mut b = vec![4, 5, 6];
let r = &mut b;
r.push(7);
```